# C pointers in linked list

Tags: c, pointers

Doing a homework and I'm having problems with, what I believe, pointers.

The assignment consists in the following:

I have a txt file where each line as a name and a password.

```
thisismyname:thisismypassword
```

I have to read this data, process it into struct linked list, run all the list and send the password to a brute-force algorithm. This algorithm, after finding  the pass, should write the pass on the struct. In the end, I should run the list and write the data to a txt file

My problem is when I find the password. It is not storing its value in the struct. At the end I can read the data, I can see that the brute-force is working but at the end, I'm only managing to write the name and pass to file. The unencrypted pass is being written as NULL so I believe is a pointer problem.

This is the code (Removed all the things that I believe are irrelevant):

```
typedef struct p {
    char *name;
    char *pass;
    char *pass_desenc;
    struct p *next_person;
} person;

typedef struct n {
    int a;
    int b;
} numbers;

int readFile(person **people) {
    FILE * fp;
    char line[100];

    if ((fp = fopen(STUDENTS_FILE, "r")) != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof (line), fp) != NULL) {
            person *p;
            char email[27] = "";
            char password[14] = "";
            char *change = strchr(line, '\n');
            if (change != NULL)
                *change = '\0';

            /* Gets email*/
            strncpy(email, line, 26);
            email[27] = '\0';

            /* Gets pass*/
            strncpy(password, line + 27, 14);
            password[14] = '\0';

            p = (person*) malloc(sizeof (person));
            if (p == NULL) {
                return -1;
            }

            p->name = (char*) malloc(strlen(email));
            if (p->name == NULL) {
                return -1;
            }
            sprintf(p->name, "%s", email);
            p->name[strlen(email)] = '\0';

            p->pass = (char*) malloc(strlen(password));
            if (p->pass == NULL) {
                return -1;
            }
            sprintf(p->pass, "%s", password);
            p->pass[strlen(password)] = '\0';

            p->next_person = (*people);
            (*people) = p;

            countPeople++;
        }
        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

void fmaps(int id, numbers pass_range, person *people) {
        /*This function will run all my list and try to uncrypt pass by pass.
            On the brute-force pass in unencrypted and when it return to this function, I can print the data.
        */
        while (people != NULL && j > 0) {
            for (i = 1; i <= PASS_SIZE && notFound == 1; i++) {
                notFound = bruteForce(i, people, &total_pass);
            }
            notFound = 1;
            count = count + total_pass;

            printf("#####Email: %s Pass: %s PassDesenq: %s \n", people->name, people->pass, people->pass_desenc);

            people = people->next_person;
            j--;
        }
}

void fcontrol(int n, person *people) {
    /*This function should write the data to a file
    I can see that all data is written as expected but people->pass_desenc is writing/printing NULL
    */

    if ((fp = fopen(STUDENTS_LOG_FILE, "a+")) != NULL) {
        while (people != NULL) {
            printf("#####1111Email: %s Pass: %s PassDesenq: %s \n", people->name, people->pass, people->pass_desenc);
            fprintf(fp, "%d%d%d%d%d%d:grupo%d:%s:%s\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec, 1, people->name, people->pass_desenc);
            people = people->next_person;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main() {

    /*Struct*/
    person *people = NULL;

    if (readFile(&people)) {
        printf("Error reading file!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /*Function to send data to brute-force*/
    fmaps(i, pass_range, people);
    /*After all data is processed, this function writes the data to a file*/
    fcontrol(NR_PROC, people);

    destroyList(&people);

    return 0;
}

int bruteForce(int size, person *people, int *total_pass) {
    int i;
    char *pass_enc;
    int *entry = (int*) malloc(sizeof (size));
    char pass[50];
    char temp;
    pass[0] = '\0';


    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        entry[i] = 0;
    }
    do {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            temp = (char) (letters[entry[i]]);
            append(pass, temp);
        }

        (*total_pass)++;

        /*Compare pass with test*/
        pass_enc = crypt(pass, salt);


        if (strcmp(pass_enc, people->pass) == 0) {

            people->pass_desenc = (char*) malloc(strlen(pass));
            if (people->pass_desenc == NULL) {
                return -1;
            }

            sprintf(people->pass_desenc, "%s", pass);
            people->pass_desenc[strlen(pass)] = '\0';
            return 0;
        }

        pass[0] = '\0';
        for (i = 0; i < size && ++entry[i] == nbletters; i++) {
            entry[i] = 0;
        }

    } while (i < size);


    free(entry);


    return 1;
}

void append(char *s, char c) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = c;
    s[len + 1] = '\0';
}

void destroyList(person **people) {
    person *aux;
    printf("\nList is being destroyed.");
    while (*people != NULL) {
        aux = *people;
        *people = (*people)->next_person;
        free(aux);
        printf(".");
    }
    printf("\nList destroyed.\n");
}
```

I believe that the changes being made in `fmaps` are local and are not passing to `main`.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: 1) `p->name = malloc(1+strlen(email));` 2) `email[27] = '\0';` is beyond the allocated size, too. 3) the same for password. 4) ` p->name[strlen(email)] = '\0';` is ugly and potentially dangerous. 5) `strncpy()` is *always wrong*.

Comment: Right away I can tell you you're overrunning array boundaries. an array of size 14 should have a maximum index set to 13 (0..13). And you're understanding of strncpy() needs a refresh. your locals email[] and password[] both are being overrun.

Comment: @wildplasser that's why one should use `strdup()` instead of reinventing the wheel. I advice OP to study the C standard library before doing anything (potentially harmful).

Comment: @H2CO3 The Standard C library (as in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 C standard) does not include `strdup()`; it is POSIX extension.

Comment: 5) sizeof is your friend. 6) your readloop will fail misarably if lines shorter than 14+27+2 happen to be present in the file. 7) don't cast malloc() s return value. 8) you don't need the parentesis in `(*people) = p;` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @wildplasser and others. Thanks for pointing all of that mistakes. managed to solve many of them but problem persists. Can´t manage to permanently add the unencrypted pass to the struct. What should i use instead of `strncopy`? I'm using the flag -ansi. All the lines have the same lenght

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, but I assume POSIX unless Windows is explicitly mentioned...

Comment: Most will tell you strncpy() is worthless. the main reason being because almost-no-one uses it right and an entire generation of engineers learned to (a) use it incorrectly, and (b) think they're safely avoiding buffer overruns in doing so, which in almost all cases, they're actually *introducing* them instead.. Rarely, it seems, do people know how it really functions, and thus I can only tell you unless you're one of them you're better off memcpy()'ing known data lengths and setting your tail-terminator manually.

Comment: @favolas: there are too many errors, and all of them of the same kind. Finding **the** error that strikes first is impossible and useless. IMO You should first correct the obvious errors, then maybe later we can go chasing the non-obvious ones.

Comment: The code presented does not compile.  If you have global variables `i` so that `fmaps()` compiles, break that habit now (global variables should be used sparingly, and should be meaningfully named).

Comment: @Favolas After reviewing the code all I can really say with constructive  criticism is you should spend some more time becoming familiar with the language, the documented behaviors of the runtime-time library routines, and above all, spend time reading as much simple, solid, *known correct* code samples. The time you spend doing so will pay off in the end.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and Jon, thanks for the info on `strdup()`, i never knew that, and have been at this a *long* time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry but removed all variable declaration to save space. Code is compiling without any errors and warnings. @WhozCraig Thanks for the criticism. If we don't practice, C is a very easy language to forget. That was what happened to me. Will have to read all again. I can see that the info returned by the bruteforce is printed inside `fmaps`. Can't understand why it is not printed in `fcontrol`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you *could* code the file reader/parser. It avoids str[n]cpy(), and does all string operations using memcpy() + the offsets + sizes. (which need to be correct in both cases, obviously)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct p {
    char *name;
    char *pass;
    // char *pass_desenc;
    struct p *next;
} person;

#define STUDENTS_FILE "students.dat"
unsigned countPeople = 0;

int readFile(person **people) {
    FILE * fp;
    char line[100];
    size_t len, pos;

    fp = fopen(STUDENTS_FILE, "r");
    if (!fp)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s:%s\n"
                , STUDENTS_FILE, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
        }

    while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) ) {
        person *p;

        len = strlen(line);

        /* remove trailng '\n', adjusting the length */
        while (len && line[len-1] == '\n') line[--len] = 0;

        /* Ignore empty lines */
        if ( !len ) continue;

        /* Library function to count the number of characters in the first argument
        ** *not* present in the second argument.
        ** This is more or less equivalent to strtok(), but
        ** 1) it doen not modify the string,
        ** 2) it returns a size_t instead of a pointer.
        */
        pos = strcspn(line, ":" );

        /* Ignore lines that don't have a colon */
        if (line[pos] != ':') continue;

        p = malloc(sizeof *p);
        if ( !p ) { fclose(fp); return -2; }
        p->next = NULL;

        p->name = malloc(1+pos);
        if ( !p->name ) { fclose(fp); return -3; } /* this could leak p ... */
        memcpy(p->name, line, pos-1);
        p->name[pos] = 0;

        p->pass = malloc(len-pos);
        if ( !p->pass ) {fclose(fp); return -4; } /* this could leak p and p->name */
        memcpy(p->pass, line+pos+1, len-pos);

        /* Instead of pushing (which would reverse the order of the LL)
        ** , we append at the tail of the LL, keeping the original order.
        */
        *people = p;
        people = &p->next ;

        countPeople++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about closing the file when you exit upon an error condition?

Comment: an excellent idea, I daresay!

Comment: @wildplasser Many many thanks. This will be a good starting point to remember C.